# Cannot build while I include own header file

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I want to use C on Linux - VSCode. Therefore, I referred tutorial [Using C++ on Linux in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) to use C/C++ extension, and accomplished to build *hello world*. Next, **I want to test "include .h" by adding adder.h/.c**:

```
//adder.h
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int a, int b);
```

```
//adder.c
#include "adder.h"
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "adder.h"
int main()
{
    printf("ret = %d\n", add(1,2));
}
```

Those code can be build on *DevC++* without any other setting. However, **it showed error message after *Terminal* -> *Run Build Task...***
:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc build active file <

Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -g /home/hughesyang/Test/c/projects/multi_files/main.c -o /home/hughesyang/Test/c/projects/multi_files/main
/tmp/ccvaDYKq.o: In function `main':
/home/hughesyang/Test/c/projects/multi_files/main.c:6: undefined reference to `add'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

I'm not sure whether **I need to modify DEFAULT tasks.json to solve that?** Or it's caused by other mistake?

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

PS. [Using C++ on Linux in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) is a C++ example. Thus, I replace g++ with gcc as compiler for C.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be rude, but why would you dabble in such complex interfaces when VSCode is clearly *only* meant to be a text editor and the terminal is where you can compile effortlessly ? You do realise VSCode is just sending the commands to the terminal *for* you ?

Comment: If you're shooting for multi-file projects and want to use VSCode I *strongly* suggest doing it with cmake. The cmake extensions make this so much easier. And as a bonus, you're halfway to an automation step you'll eventually want anyway.

Comment: Please don't post images of text! Not only do they not work with screen-readers, they also aren't searchable and (for what I tried to do) it's not possible to copy-paste part of the text shown in these images. And that goes for the build output as well (which should be enough to read to understand *why* you have a problem, since it shows only a single source file being built).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I've modified it to pure text format.

Comment: @WhozCraig https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux that's what you mention? I'll study how to use it! Thanks

Comment: You'll also want to hit up a good cmake tutorial. You will barely have to scratch the surface to get something up and functional in your linux+vscode environment, however. Basic cmakelists.txt configuration is pretty trivial on small throw together projects. That's another reason to move to that paradigm. As your projects grow you'll begin to learn more and more about options in cmake as well. It's an incredibly powerful system, and its integration with vscode via extensions is pretty damn good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @WhozCraig's hint. **It needs to use cmake to accomplish that.** After referring [Get started with CMake Tools on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux) and **adding adder.c inside the add_executable()** of CMakeLists.txt, it works!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(helloworld_cmake VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(helloworld_cmake main.c adder.c)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```